# If Singletons are bad then how do you store global state for a framework

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

If singletons are considered bad for global state, particularly state that can affects the main execution of code, then how should global state for, say, a web framework be handled?

The immediate things that come to mind are:

- Base Url
- Base File Path
- General configs
- Logging instance
- etc

I cant see any other way than a singleton for access to these such as an App() class or similar?

Comment: Where did you get the reference that singletons are considered bad for global state?

Comment: I was under the impression this was a general consensus among developers?  I must be wrong then - in which case i will use them more!  Thanks :)

Comment: @MartyWallace the real problem is not about using a singleton or not, it's *why* you think you may need a singleton.

Comment: @Marcelo - singletons are per class-loader so if an app is using more than one class-loader keeping the global state in a singleton may be problematic.

Comment: @pl47ypus In what cases do you normally use one than more class-loader?

Comment: @Marcelo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - so that is the crux of my question.  How would i go about handling the state i mentioned without using a singleton?

Comment: It's Global State which is "the real bad boy. Wikipedia cites William Wulf and Mary Shaw, “Global Variable Considered Harmful”, ACM SIGPLAN Notices, volume 8, issue 2, 1973 February, pp. 28–34. I don't think there's been any serious argument in the last forty years. Singletons just add unnecessary complication on top of global state.

Comment: @Marcelo - "Sometimes in Java you need to load a set of classes that are isolated from the classpath. For instance, you might need to support the capability to plugin a library to your main application and you want to be able to isolate the libraries used by the plugins from your main application." the rest is here: http://tech.puredanger.com/2006/11/09/classloader/

Comment: https://twitter.com/codemonkey_uk/status/157463012284960769

Comment: @pl47ypus I would like to see a real world application of this in a web application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - i'm actually working on such one (we serve hundreds of  millions requests and process 3-5 TB of new data every day).

Answer (score 5):

Load this data in a place that is already *global* for your application. For instance, in Web applications, you can store this data in application scope i.e. [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Also, you can use a framework that already handles a *global* state per certain context like Spring.

By the way, there are cases like *Logging instances* (i.e. `Logger logger`) that aren't stored in singleton instances but in each class, marked as `static final`.

More info related to the long-never-endind discussion about Singleton pattern usage:

- [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/1065197)